# How does closure access more than 1 parameter?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm not grokking what's happening here. How does the closure sort the elements and not throw an out of bounds error when it hits the end of the array? And why can't I use a 3rd parameter via $2?

Is sorted a builtin method for Arrays? (I think I just answered my own question but I'd still like to get some feedback.)

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sorted{$1 > $0}
print(sortedNumbers)
```

Produces

```
[7, 12, 19, 20]
```

Comment: Command-click on `sorted` in the Xcode editor and you'll see how it is defined (including examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `sorted` is built-in to Swift Arrays.  It can do it without a closure if the element type implements `Comparable`. So, you could omit the closure in your case and get the same result.

The sort algorithm calls the closure for pairs of elements at a time to find out their order, which is why it takes two parameters.

Sort algorithms generally are designed so that they can infer the whole order of the array with minimal pair-wise comparisons (it shouldn't need to compare every element to every other one, nor does it do this by simply looping through the array to the end).

This might help you understand (sort algorithm visualization): https://visualgo.net/en/sorting?slide=1

Answer (score 1):

You're using the method on this page: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2296815-sorted

`func sorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) -> Bool) -> [Element]`

Notice it takes a closure with a signature of `(Element, Element) -> Bool`. Therefore you provide it a function that takes two elements and returns a `Bool` indicating whether or not the first element should come before the second element.

The function automatically handles the bounds of the array and only provides valid elements to the closure so there is no out of bounds error.